# react-navigation Type Check

Tags: typescript, react-navigation

My code is like this.

```
type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  HomeTextInput: undefined;
  HomeSearchResult: {searchText: string};
};

type HomeSearchResultRouteProp = RouteProp<
  RootStackParamList,
  'HomeSearchResult'
>;

const route = useRoute<'HomeSearchResultRouteProp'>();

const {searchText} = route.params;
```

But I met Error: TS2339: Property 'params' does not exist on type 'Pick<Route<"HomeSearchResult">, "key" | "name">'.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `react-router` doesn't have hook `useRoute` maybe you mean `useRouteMatch`?

Comment: Sorry. It's not react-router, react-navigation. Sorry. This is my fault